# Dealing with long SQL scripts and SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook, ipython

The problem is that I have a long SQL Script (that contains variables and comments and many lines of code) that I need to re-produce the results of which in Jupyter Notebooks.

I have already tried "tidying" the SQL into a string, but it is many lines and would take too long. For system architecture reasons I cannot create a procedure or view that encapsulates the script.

```
# The basic structure of my problem sans actual detail as not required 
engine = create_engine("server/database=connect") 
SQL = "select * from foo" #Insert very long script here
SQL_DF = pd.read_sql(SQL, engine)
```

I am hoping there is an informal way or trick to either convert a whole cell (containing my script text) to a string variable. Or if someone has another method of turning long SQL scripts into strings that can be used easily with SQL Alchemy.

Comment: Try reading in SQL script as regular text file then `split` resulting string by semicolon or whatever is used as statement delimiter. Then iterate through split lines to call `cursor.execute`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use triple quote:
`"""select * from foo
some more code
and more
etc"""`

or you may use `\` in the end of each line:
`"select * from foo\
some more code\
and more\
etc"`